# Take difference of two columns in R resulting in a new third column

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

So far I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Account     Total     Mastered     Not_Mastered
1           1         NA           NA
2           12        2            10    
3           4         NA           NA
4           51        50           1
```

The code I have is: 
`Table$not_mastered = (Table$total - Table$mastered)`

My goal is to subtract the 'mastered' column from the 'total' column to result in a third column 'not_mastered' and if there is no value in the 'mastered' column then I want the new column to have the same value as the 'total' column. Shown below.

```
Account     Total     Mastered     Not_Mastered
1           1         NA           1
2           12        2            10    
3           4         NA           4
4           51        50           1
```

How can I skip over the NA values in the mastered column and rewrite the values from the total column?

Comment: `Table$Not_Mastered <- ifelse(is.na(Table$Mastered), Table$Total, Table$Total-Table$Mastered)`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of software you are using, you should be able to catch those with a simple if-loop.

```
for index=1: (number of rows of data) % looks at each row, one at a time
     if Mastered(index)==NA  % if the value is the Mastered column is NA
          NotMastered(index)=Total(index);
     else
          NotMastered(index)=Total(index)-Mastered(index);
     end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `replace` to change the NA values to 0 and then do the difference

```
with(df1, Total - replace(Mastered, is.na(Mastered), 0))
#[1]  1 10  4  1
```